# Error: Cannot find module "." when passing image to child component

Tags: reactjs

Im always getting error here:

[image]

Im trying to pass image urls to child component from parent.But i have been always failed having such errors.
Is there any other way to pass image urls array to child components?

Parent:

```
const { classes } = props;
    return( 
        <Grid
          container
          spacing={24}
          direction="row"
          justify="space-around"
          alignItems="flex-start"
        > 
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={10} lg={8} xl={6}> 
               <Slider imgPath={images} /> 
            </Grid>
        </Grid> 
    );
```

Child:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Slider from 'react-animated-slider';
import horizontalCss from 'react-animated-slider/build/horizontal.css'; 

function slider(props) {
    const { classes } = props;
    var html=[];
    var imgPath=props.imgPath;

    for (var i = 0; i <imgPath.length; i++) { 
        var path = "'" + imgPath[i] + "'"; 
        var path1 = "<img src={require("+path+")} />"; 
        html.push(<img src={require(path)}/>);
    }

    return(
        <Slider autoplay={5000} classNames={horizontalCss}> 
            {html} 
        </Slider> 
    );
} 

export default slider;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use dynamic names in `require`, it needs static solvable paths. So, here is an example how you can do it. Just adjust the code to your situation.

```
const App = () => {
  const images = [
    { id: 1, path: require( "./images/img1.jpg" ) },
    { id: 2, path: require( "./images/img2.jpg" ) },
    { id: 3, path: require( "./images/img3.jpg" ) },
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      {
        images.map( image => (
          <Img key={image.id} image={image} />
        ) )
      }
    </div>
  );
};

const Img = ( { image } ) => (
  <div>
    <p>{image.id}</p>
    <img width="100" src={image.path} />
  </div>
);
```

---

As an alternative to this method here an easier one that I've learned recently:

```
const App = () => {
  const images = [
    { id: 1, path: "./images/img1.jpg" },
    { id: 2, path: "./images/img2.jpg" },
    { id: 3, path: "./images/img3.jpg" },
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      {
        images.map( image => (
          <Img key={image.id} image={image} />
        ) )
      }
    </div>
  );
};

const Img = ( { image } ) => (
  <div>
    <p>{image.id}</p>
    <img width="100" src={require( "" + image.path )} />
  </div>
);
```

`require( "" + image.path )` is doing the trick here. With this method, instead of writing so many `require`s, we can use one in our child component.

Comment: Tried this exact thing, didn't help for me. Wonder if there is updated solution?

Comment: This solution still works. There should be another issue. You can create a brand new question about your issue.